# Binomial Theorem coefficient sum...

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Recently I encountered a question but its answer as well as the way the author of the book has solved the question seemed wrong to me..

> Find the sum of the coefficients of the expansion of
>
> $$ (1+x-3x^2)^{2163} $$

I expanded the expression take it  as $(1+(x-3x^2)$ and then I put the $(x-3x^2)$ as 1 thus leaving only the coefficients and hence putting the same values in the expression ( i.e. $ (x-3x^2)=1$) gave the answer as $2^{2163}$ but the answer according to the book is -1. The authors just put x=1 which seems absurd to me. Please help and tell me if am wrong.

Comment: Hint: Imagine that the polynomial has already been multiplied out.  How does plugging in $x=1$ add up the coefficients in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint put $x=1$ as $1$  doesn't affect the binomial coefficients of an expansion.

Comment: But if i expand binomially and them in the terms like (x-3x^2) switch x=1 that won't make the coefficients free from all the terms just like it does in (1+x)^n. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Go for multinomial theorem and see whether $x=1$ affects anything

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now i understood that if I switch x=1 in multinomial theorem, then what I get is simply the sum of coefficients.